# How to Show search suggestion in Autocomplete for android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, autosuggest, search-suggestion

As a user when I start typing into the search field I want to see some autocomplete options based on matching terms in the **paragraph(String)** so that I don't have to type really long terms using a tiny phone keyboard.

**Note:**

The Suggestion will come from particular content or String

Comment: what adapter are you using?

Comment: Try this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: post your filter code in an adapter, or pls mention the library link if u r using a library

Answer (score 0):

The following link is for the Android Developers forum that should get you started along. Link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

The example as provided in the link for creating text view which suggests various countries names while the user is typing:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         //initialise the adapter for give n array of strings to be searched with
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView autotextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);

         //set the adapter for the Autocomplete TextView
         autotextView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

Comment: did you notice that OP tagged his question with `autocompletetextview` tag?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Let me change that. @pskink

Comment: @Nithinlal, I wouldn't be so sure about that. Otherwise we would have seen a more detailed question.

Comment: Don't answer the question which is not clear, your answer may be devoted

Comment: @Nithinlal, what I see is the OP asking for guidance in getting started. Its not a crime to answer questions that might be wrongly asked. If am to looked at from wrong side for providing answer to the OP, I am not sure what to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Make a layout containing autoCompleteTextView

```
<AutoCompleteTextView   
android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"     
android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

then in java code list all the suggestions in the array,

```
String[] suggestions ={"Android","java"};

//or get it via array.xml of res, using 
//String[] suggestions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.suggarray);

text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,suggestions);

text.setAdapter(adapter);
text.setThreshold(1);
```